# JOOQ vs SQL Queries

Tags: jooq

I am on jooq queries now...I feel the SQL queries looks more readable and maintainable and why we need to use JOOQ instead of using native SQL queries.

Can someone explains few reason for using the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are the top value propositions that you will never get with native (string based) SQL:

- [Dynamic SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/) is what jOOQ is really really good at. You can compose the most complex queries dynamically based on user input, configuration, etc. and still be sure that the query will run correctly.
- An often underestimated effect of dynamic SQL is the fact that you will be able to think of SQL as an algebra, because instead of writing difficult to compose native SQL syntax (with all the keywords, and weird parenthesis rules, etc.), you can think in terms of expression trees, because you're effectively building an expression tree for your queries. Not only will this allow you to implement more sophisticated features, such as SQL transformation for [multi tenancy](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/) or [row level security](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq), but every day things like [transforming a set of values into a SQL set operation](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/27/map-reducing-a-set-of-values-into-a-dynamic-sql-union-query/)
- Vendor agnosticity. As soon as you have to support more than one SQL dialect, writing SQL manually is close to impossible because of the many subtle differences in dialects. The jOOQ documentation illustrates this e.g. with the [`LIMIT` clause](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/). Once this is a problem you have, you have to use either JPA (much restricted query language: JPQL) or jOOQ (almost no limitations with respect to SQL usage).
- Type safety. Now, you will get type safety when you write views and stored procedures as well, but very often, you want to run ad-hoc queries from Java, and there is no guarantee about table names, column names, column data types, or syntax correctness when you do SQL in a string based fashion, e.g. using JDBC or JdbcTemplate, etc. By the way: jOOQ encourages you to use as many views and stored procedures as you want. They fit perfectly in the jOOQ paradigm.
- [Code generation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/). Which leads to more type safety. Your database schema becomes part of your client code. Your client code no longer compiles when your queries are incorrect. Imagine someone renaming a column and forgetting to refactor the 20 queries that use it. IDEs only provide some degree of safety when writing the query for the first time, they don't help you when you refactor your schema. With jOOQ, your build fails and you can fix the problem long before you go into production.
- Documentation. The generated code also acts as documentation for your schema. Comments on your tables, columns turn into Javadoc, which you can introspect in your client language, without the need for looking them up in the server.
- Data type bindings are very easy with jOOQ. Imagine using a library of 100s of [stored procedures](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/stored-procedures/). Not only will you be able to access them type safely (through code generation), as if they were actual Java code, but you don't have to worry about the tedious and useless activity of binding each single in and out parameter to a type and value.

There are a ton of more advanced features derived from the above, such as:

- The availability of a [parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/) and by consequence the possibility of [translating SQL](https://www.jooq.org/translate/).
- Schema management tools, such as [diffing two schema versions](https://www.jooq.org/diff/)
- Basic ActiveRecord support, including some nice things like [optimistic locking](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-optimistic-locking/).
- [Synthetic SQL features](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/synthetic-sql-clauses/) like [type safe implicit JOIN](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/)
- [Query By Example](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/query-by-example/).
- A [nice integration in Java streams](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/lazy-fetching-with-streams/) or [reactive streams](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/reactive-fetching/).
- [Some more advanced SQL transformations](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/sql-transformation/ansi-join-to-table-lists/) (this is work in progress).
- [Export](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-csv/) and [import](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-csv/) functionality
- Simple [JDBC mocking functionality](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/mocking-connection/), including a [file based database mock](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/mock-file-database/).
- [Diagnostics](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/diagnostics/)

And, if you occasionally think something is much simpler to do with plain native SQL, then just:

- [Use plain native SQL, also in jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

Disclaimer: As I work for the vendor, I'm obviously biased.